# Building Pull Requests with TeamCity 8.1.5

Tags: git, github, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity 8.1.5, and trying to build all branches and pull requests on a public repository. I have followed a few blogs, like:

- http://michaelsync.net/2013/11/05/teamcity-tip-building-all-pull-requests-and-updating-the-status-to-github
- http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/

I've tried lots of variations of the following, but only the default branch ever builds.

```
+:refs/pull/(*/merge)
+:refs/heads/*
```

I have two initial questions:

1. Do I need to be a contributor for this to work?
2. Does TeamCity need to be authenticated as the contributor user in order to work?

Thanks.